# Can you be too detailed in fantasy writing?

Tags: description

I am wondering if there is such a thing as “too detailed” in writing. If yes, then I want to know if I am doing it. I will insert a descriptive paragraph from my own writing below.

> Its scaly head was easily the size of a large minivan in the shape of a diamond, with a glistening black forked tongue the length of my body. It’s eyes were glowing a yellowish-green like headlights in the dying sun. It opened its mouth, revealing fangs the length of my arms, dripping with inky black venom. It’s mouth was ringed with a crusty brown substance, and with horror I realized it was dried blood. The loudest, most horrible noise I’d ever heard shook the ground at my feet. It sounded almost like the worlds largest maraca.

Is this too descriptive? Or just right? If it’s good you should be able to guess what kind of animal this is.

Comment: Do minivans exist in your fantasy world?

Comment: "It’s eyes were glowing a yellowish-green like headlights in the dying sun."  Do headlights glow yellowish-green in the dying sun?

Comment: I meant that it’s eyes looked like head lights, not that headlights are green.

Comment: And yes minivans exist. All the humans came from OUR world, so I avoided the problem of phrases, objects, stuff like that.

Comment: That's the problem.  It is ambiguous.  To me it reads like headlights glow yellowish green in the dying sun and the dragon's eyes look like that.

Comment: It’s a rattle snake. You know, the venom, fangs, rattle. It’s says that later but I didn’t include it. It could have been a dragon because they exist here, but there are also giant animals which are some of the monsters we discussed yesterday. The main character is making the connection of its glowing eyes to headlights. She uses a simile because it’s similar, not identical. And some headlights ARE yellow.

Comment: No rattle in your excerpt.  Dragon's have venom in some fantasy settings.  A giant rattlesnake doesn't leap to mind from your description and the (fantasy) setting.

Comment: The rattle is the loud noise. I don’t include the part of the sentence that says “like a maraca” I didn’t think it was important to the question.

Comment: It has always fascinated me how fictional characters stop to mentally catalog dangerous things when they should be running for cover or soiling their trousers.

Comment: Yes, some headlights are yellow.  They have (or had) them in France.  I see them occasionally still on French cars when I'm there or when they come over the border into Germany.

Answer (score 3):

It's great to include descriptive details, but as with many things in writing, there's a limit to how far you should go. If you include too many details, you run the risk of coming across as pretentious, overly flowery, or writing "[purple prose](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PurpleProse)." This becomes very easy to slip into as a fantasy writer, especially if you use a lot of adverbs, flowery descriptions, and metaphors.

I don't think your paragraph slides too far in that direction, but there are some unnecessary descriptive words here. If I was your editor, I would definitely change "headlights in the dying sun" to just "headlights." The former feels a little purple and pretentious to me. (You also have a few grammar and apostrophe issues, but that's not relevant to the question.)

You also have some unnecessary descriptions. "The ground at my feet"? Of course the ground is at your feet - that's where ground always is! Take off "at my feet." And so on. Similarly, you don't need a lot of these adjectives and adverbs. All minivans are "large," and "easily" is not necessary, either.

The point I'm trying to make here is that **whenever you can cut out a word without fundamentally changing the meaning of the sentence or the passage, cut it out.** This will drastically help with the wordiness of your writing and make it easier to read.

If I was an editor working on your passage, this is how I would revise it.

Original:

> Its scaly head was easily the size of a large minivan in the shape of a diamond, with a glistening black forked tongue the length of my body. It’s eyes were glowing a yellowish-green like headlights in the dying sun. It opened its mouth, revealing fangs the length of my arms, dripping with inky black venom. It’s mouth was ringed with a crusty brown substance, and with horror I realized it was dried blood. The loudest, most horrible noise I’d ever heard shook the ground at my feet. **(88 words)**

My shortened version:

> Its scaly head was minivan-sized, diamond-shaped, with a glistening black forked tongue the length of my body; its eyes glowed yellowish-green like headlights, and when it opened its mouth, it revealed fangs the length of my arm, dripping with inky black venom. Its mouth was crusted brown, and I realized with horror it was dried blood as the loudest, most horrible noise I'd ever heard shook the ground. **(68 words)**